# Properly setting up the robots.txt for magento

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, robots.txt

I want to remove the pages from search engine by using robots.txt to not to index such pages.
The repeated URL's Containing the same content appear as

website.com/category.html?dir=asc&mode=list&order=price&p=anypage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To block those kind of URLs with `robots.txt` you could use the following lines:

```
Disallow: /*?dir=*
Disallow: /*&dir=*
Disallow: /*?mode=*
Disallow: /*&mode=*
Disallow: /*?order=*
Disallow: /*&order=*
Disallow: /*?p=*
Disallow: /*&p=*
```

This will tell user-agents not to access **all URLs** which contain `ascending/decending` sorting, `grid/list` mode, `position/name/price` order and `pagination`. To learn more about robots.txt files [click here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961&rd=1).

> **IMPORTANT:** I'm not saying that this is the best way to deal with Magentos sorting and pagination options in relation to duplicate
>   content. There is a lot of
>   [discussion](http://www.creare.co.uk/magento-seo-category-filters-duplicate-content-issues)
>   about what really is the best way to do this. For instance, you could
>   also use [Google Webmaster Tools
>   URLParameters](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080548?hl=en)
>   to give Google information about how to handle URLs containing
>   specific parameters. You should be very careful when trying to block URLs because you might 
>   unintentionally block the wrong pages.

Comment: Thanks i first tried using the robots.txt file but it didn't worked out well then i used Google Webmaster tools parameters . But the problem i am facing right now is that the indexed layered URLs still appear in GSE.

Comment: If you have set things up correctly then Google should drop those URLs sooner or later (I think). But don't expect instant results from `robots.txt` or `URL Parameters`. This will take some time (it may take up to half a year). You could use the `URL Removal Tool` in Google Webmaster Tools to tell Google to remove those URLs. But before you do, read more about this [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/1724262?hl=en&ref_topic=4589100).

Answer (score 0):

Layered navigation is a SEO mess indeed. Another solution you could try is setting **NOINDEX,FOLLOW** for everything except page parameter (**?p=x**), adding **rel prev** & **rel next** and enabling **rel canonical**.

Here is one way to set robots meta

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0.0">
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setRobots">
                <value helper="mymodule/getRobotsDirective"/>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

And our helper file with getRobotsDirective() method

```
public function getRobotsDirective()
{
    $allowedKeys = array('id' => 0, 'p' => 0);
    $diff = array_diff_key($this->_getRequest()->getParams(), $allowedKeys);

    if (!empty($diff)) {
        return 'NOINDEX,FOLLOW';
    }

    return null;
}
```

Please keep in mind that this was done in 10 minutes and this code is not tested. Like @ForMat said, You should be very careful when trying to block URLs.